# Get the mysql password of salt-minion from salt-master

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I want to execute a query from salt-master to salt-minion using mysql.query .

I am setting the mysql information of salt-minion as follows.

/etc/salt/minion file

```
mysql.host: 'localhost'
mysql.port: 3306
mysql.user: 'root'
mysql.pass: 'root123'
mysql.db: 'mysql'
mysql.unix_socket: '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'
mysql.charset: 'utf8'
```

Is there any way to get the mysql password specified in salt-master from salt-minion?

salt-master setting
/etc/salt/pillar/mysql.sls

```
mysql:
  mysqlrootpassword: 'root123'
```

salt-minion
/etc/salt/minion

```
mysql.pass: salt['pillar.get']('mysql:mysqlrootpassword', '')
mysql.pass: {{ pillar['mysql']['mysqlrootpassword'] }}
mysql.pass: {{ salt['pillar.get']('mysql:mysqlrootpassword', '') }}
```

All three of the above do not bring the password.

Comment: Have a look at the [salt-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/salt-formula). It can template the minion config - among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jinja templates in the minion config.

The mysql module will take config directly from pillar, so simply change your pillar definition to:

```yaml
mysql.pass: 'root123'
```